# Javascript : Unexpected empty element in array with different key types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can someone explain what's going on in this JavaScript code:

```js
    let arr = [];

    arr["foo"] = "11";
    arr["sd"] = "12";
    arr[1] = "13";

    console.log(arr.length); //2
    console.log(arr) // [empty, "13", foo: "11", sd: "12"]
```

Why is there an `empty` element in the array?

Also, why the Array `length` equals 2 and not 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Property names that are not numeric do not count towards the length of an array in JavaScript. By setting `arr[1]` you force the length to be 2, because the length is always one greater than the maximum numeric property name. Thus your array implicitly has an empty element 0, an element 1 with a value, and then two other properties with string keys.

Comment: Note that "numeric" property names must be positive integers that fit in 31 bits.